# Laravel dependency injection not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm using resource controllers in my laravel app and I'm trying to use dependancy injection but it's not working on a particular model and controller.

This works:

```
/**
* Display the specified resource.
*
* @param  \App\Booking  $booking
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function show(Booking $booking)
{
    return $booking;
}
```

But for some infuriating reason this doesn't:

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\SchoolEvent  $schoolEvent
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(SchoolEvent $schoolEvent)
{
    return $schoolEvent;
}
```

My Routes look like this:

```
// Events
Route::resource('events', Resources\SchoolEventController::class);

// Bookings
Route::resource('bookings', Resources\BookingController::class);
```

For some reason /bookings/1 returns a filled object but /events/1 returns an empty one. Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Change the injected variable name to `$event` to match the route parameter name `{event}`:

```php
public function show(SchoolEvent $event)
```

You can see the route parameters with this command:

```
php artisan route:list
```

Comment: That works too, can you tell me why? That really seems like a bug.

Comment: 'event' its the parameter name in resources routes, you can see them with `php artisan route:list` Its because of Model Binding like @Alexey also pointed

Comment: well its not a bug if you dont give the same name to the injected variable and to the route parameter, laravel gives you a correct Model instance but not loaded, as you noticed.

Comment: Ah, now I did suspect the route name would be making the difference but what would be the correct route if I did want to call the variable $schoolEvent. Thanks guys, not trying to be difficult just trying to work out where I went wrong so I can avoid it later.

Comment: Got it, ignore that. Would have to be /schoolEvent. But I could use /shool-event and call the variable $school_event.
Neat! Thanks for the route:list tip @dparoli

Comment: no problem, I did the same error in the past I know its a bit disappointing

Comment: you can change the name of the parameter for a  resource route, i.e: `Route::resource('user', 'AdminUserController', ['parameters' => [
    'user' => 'admin_user'
]]);`

Comment: I fixed a similar issue with @dparoli help. I had to set my web.php route param to {customer} and route::model binding to 'customer' so that it would match $customer in the Controller. NOTE however - The capital letter difference WORKS IN WINDOWS 11 with PHP CLI SERVER. So, this was incredibly difficult to troubleshoot 

Answer (score 5):

Change the model name to `Event` to make [model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding) work.

> Since the `$user` variable is type-hinted as the `App\User` Eloquent model and the variable name matches the `{user}` URI segment, Laravel will automatically inject the model instance that has an ID matching the corresponding value from the request URI

Comment: Yep that worked. Can you tell me why? The only reason I didn't do that was because Event can be a keyword and I know laravel has event broadcasting (which I've not used - that may be obvious)

Comment: @lainChambers I've updated my answer with the explanation from the documentation.

Comment: Thanks but that just explains that the typecasting will automatically load an instance of the model using the ID, it doesn't explain why the variable name being different from the model name works and the variable names artisan created dont

Comment: You're absolutely right. Only thing I didn't realised was that - because these were resource controllers - Laravel was automatically naming that segment.

Answer (score 1):

There is another possible solution.

As has been explained Laravel tries to inject an instance, but there is a mismatch between the URI segment name and the variable.

Laravel allows to explicitly bind a Model to a slug in the RouteServiceProvider within the boot() method.

In your case:

```
public function boot()
{
   parent::boot();

   // binds the slug event to our SchoolEvent model
   Route::model('event', \App\SchoolEvent::class);
}
```

See:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#explicit-binding

I feel both solutions are viable, but personally prefer this one. All non-default slugs are in one place rather than in the individual controllers and I keep using artisan to quickly generate the basic controller code.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Route::resource, this will automatically generate all routes and the name for parameters that comes into each route.

To know what is the name, run `php artisan route:list` at your terminal. After that you will see the name that each route is waiting. Use this name into your Controller.

In your case, probably will be $school_event.

If you doesn't like the name you can use parameters function like this:

```
Route::resource(**'events'**, Resources\SchoolEventController::class)
    ->parameters([
        **'events'** => 'here_the_name_you_want'
]);
```

**Work on Laravel 5.5!**

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters